# z-transform and roc

Tags: z-transform

I am a bit confused.
I have the function
\begin{equation}
F(z)= \frac{2z}{z^2 -1}
\end{equation}
So I get two poles, in 1 and -1. But I am a bit confused, which is my region of convergence? Should it be between 1 and -1 ? Also, normally I find the z-transform always with $z^{-1}$. Can I directly work with my function, or should I transform it so that I have $z^{-1}$ instead of $z$ ?
Thanks!

Comment: two possibilities, depending on the ROC : for $|z| > 1$ : $F(z) = \frac{2z^{-1}}{1-z^{-2}} = 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{-2k-1}$, or for $|z| < 1$ : $F(z) = \frac{-2z}{1-z^2} = - 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{2k+1}$

Comment: you can see that the Z-transform $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x_n z^{-n}$ of a causal signal $(x_n)$ has a ROC of the form $|z| > a$, while the Z-transform of a anti-causal signal has a ROC of the form $|z| < a$  (causal means $x_n = 0$ for $n$ negative enough)

Comment: I know I am dealing with causal signals. Does this mean that I can "neglect" the pole in -1 because is "out of the scope" in my case?Did I understand correctly? Thanks!

Comment: You understood something incorrectly, but I don't know what. In my 1st comment I just used the geometric series, that for $|x| < 1$ : $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty x^k$, and I divided the numerator and denominator of $F(z)$ by $z^2$

Answer (score 1):

$$F(z) = \frac{2z}{z^2 - 1}$$

By using partial fraction technique

$$F(z) = \frac{1}{z+1} + \frac{1}{z-1}$$

$$ a^{n}u(n) \rightleftharpoons \frac{z}{z-a} ROC : |z| > |a|$$

$$ a^{n-1}u(n-1) \rightleftharpoons \frac{1}{z-a} ROC : |z| > |a|$$

$$(-a)^{n-1} u(n-1) \rightleftharpoons \frac{1}{z+a}  ROC : |z| > |a|$$

Both Z transforms exist only for      $$|z| > |a|$$

Hence ROC : $$|z| > |1|$$

And Inverse Z transform will be :

$$f(n) = [(1^{n-1}) + (-1^{n-1})] u(n-1)$$